# Why are more Pixel used in resulting PDF than in source html?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I used this Code, to Download a Webpage with an Image in the css file, but it is scaled too big in the pdf File.
The Picture has 120 Pixel width and is shown 185 Pixel width.
For Camparison, I Build in a 10 Pixel Line, which is shown with 12 Pixel.

But why? and how can I solve it?

I can't post the Question without further Details, but I don't know anything, which is usefull for you to know, but Maybe it helps:

I work in a archiving Department, with the Order to archive Informations which are accessible in their Webpage, but at the end, the Look just isn't how the Creators want it to be.
I tried to use a local CSS File instead, but realised, that it is not what I want.
I have to use my workflow more often and have to take the css Files they offer and just convert the html Page correctly to PDF.

Thanks in advance for reading,
I tried to make the Code contain everything what could be important to know but Nothing more.

The Dependencies of the Project are:

- com.itextpdf kernel 7.1.7
- com.itextpdf styled-xml-parser 7.1.7
- com.itextpdf svg 7.1.7
- com.itextpdf pdfa 7.1.7
- org.slf4j-simple 1.6.1

```java
package ueberordnungen;

import java.io.IOException; 
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Worker3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

        //eine spezielle URL heraus picken
        String kongressURL = "https://www.egms.de/dynamic/de/meetings/vnda2019/index.htm";

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(kongressURL).get();

        System.out.println("-----Titel: "+ doc.title());
        Element content = doc.child(0);
        content.getElementById("navigation_language").remove();
        content.getElementById("navigation").remove();
        content.getElementsByAttributeValue("href", "/static/css/gms-framework.css").first().remove();
        content.getElementsByClass("hidden_navigation").first().remove();
        content.getElementById("page").before(content.getElementById("header"));
        content.getElementsByTag("script").remove();
        content.getElementById("owner_links_container").attr("style", "border-top:10px solid #060");

        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        properties.setBaseUri(kongressURL);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("content.pdf");
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(content.html(), new PdfDocument(writer), properties);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the URL (if public) or the relevant data  to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: now, I changed the Code, so everyone can try it by themselves.

Comment: PDF files measure things in points (like a printer), not pixels (like a computer screen).  At a particular zoom level, a 100 x 100 point box in the PDF could be 1000 x 1000 pixels, or 10 x 10, or whatever on screen.  (Yes, at 100% zoom, pixels == points, though a transformation matrix can through all that right out the window)

Comment: Having said all that, your site may well be using some CSS attribute that iText doesn't support.  Last time I checked ( > 8 years ago) iText didn't support anywhere near all of CSS.  Their support is almost certainly better, but I'd be shocked if it were perfect.

Comment: okay? I used 100% Zoom Level and the Problem behind it is, that for Example the 120 width Picture ob Web has enough Space because the style=padding-left: 120px;. The padding did work, but the Picture is bigger, so it's inconsistent and the Output PDF doesn't look like the Input Website. (somehow like it should look like)

Comment: I just measured that green top border you introduced for testing, both by looking into the PDF and by using the measuring tool of Adobe Reader. In both cases I get 7.5 pt which is exactly 10px, assuming 1px = 1/96in.

Comment: The problem might be that the unit px is somewhat ambiguous: For print media (and resolution-less targets like PDFs) one usually has 1px = 1/96in (real life inches). For screen media, on the other hand, 1px usually actually refers to the whole number of device pixels that best approximates the reference pixel. Now there is no such dynamic unit in PDFs (PDFs are designed to always look the same and not change based on some output device resolution), so iText assumes 1px = 1/96in (real life inches).

Comment: Concerning the image: iText appears to display it at one image pixel per pt while the browser displays it at one image pixel per px. This might be considered an issue, in particular as iText does not appear to support `background-size` yet.

Comment: I dont know about the Line - why i see something else. But that was just a Test. The main Problem is: the picture is shown bigger than it is - so it doesn't look good and it doesn't fit in his Place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText 7 adds background images at a scale of one image pixel per pt, see `AbstractRenderer.drawBackground`:

```
PdfXObject backgroundXObject = backgroundImage.getImage();
...
Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(backgroundArea.getX(), backgroundArea.getTop() - backgroundXObject.getHeight(),
        backgroundXObject.getWidth(), backgroundXObject.getHeight());
...
drawContext.getCanvas().addXObject(backgroundXObject, imageRectangle);
```

*As you see in the code, the width and height values of the image (which contain the horizontal and vertical number of pixels of the bitmap image) are used as is as width and height of a rectangle into which the image eventually is scaled. As the units used in canvas drawing operations are user space units which default to <sup>1</sup>/<sub>72</sub>in, the image is displayed at 72 image pixels per inch or 1 image pixel per pt.*

Web browsers usually display images by default at 1 image pixel per px or 96 image pixels per inch.

Your example web page mostly is layout'ed using absolute positions given in px = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>96</sub>in. Thus, the different scale at which the images are drawn by a web browser or by iText result in different appearances, in particular not a pleasing appearance in iText in the case at hand:

- In Chrome:

  [image: Chrome screen shot]
- in iText:

  [image: Screen shot of iText generated PDF]

You can make iText draw background images more like the browsers by replacing the center code line above calculating `imageRectangle` by

```
Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(backgroundArea.getX(), backgroundArea.getTop() - backgroundXObject.getHeight(),
        backgroundXObject.getWidth() * .75f, backgroundXObject.getHeight() * .75f);
```

- in iText, patched as proposed above:

  [image: screen shot of patched iText generated PDF]

Actually this code place appears to be the appropriate place to also start adding support for `background-size` which currently is not supported here.

Beware: I'm not really deep into iText 7 HTML to PDF conversion code, so I cannot really tell whether this patch has undesirable side effects.

#### Is this a bug?

Strictly speaking it isn't, at least as far as I skimmed through the CSS specification:

The HTML page does not set a `background-size` here. Thus, the *intrinsic size* of the background image shall be used. Unfortunately, though, *CSS does not define how the intrinsic dimensions are found in general.* Thus, the web page essentially left the scale of the background image to the whim of the HTML client...

If iText 7 HTML to PDF aims at producing results in line with browser outputs, though, it had better change its default scale here to match that of those browsers.

---

I just realized that the `AbstractRenderer` I patched is not in the html2pdf project but instead in the core iText 7 layout project.

Thus, changing the size *here* probably is a bad idea, at least if one uses iText 7 not only for html2pdf but also directly.

Nonetheless, that code position is appropriate for introducing support for some background-size attribute. html2pdf then could extend the `BackgroundApplierUtil` so that it always sets that new core attribute to a value appropriate for creating an appearance in line with what browsers display.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm somehow fascinated about how someone can see inside those Projects. I just need the Experience, what can be done in that case.
should I fork itext, can I override the Function for my project or what?
Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: If you need that fix **now**, whatever the later maintenance problems may be, go ahead, fork, patch the fork, and use the fork. If you can wait a bit but want to keep maintenance problems low, ask iText support to fix this, probably with a reference here. If you want to give the fix a direction, also fork, patch, and make the patch a merge request.