# How can make the Header look the same in PDF (html2pdf) as in the Browser?

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext7

I am working towards archiving Information from Website via PDF Format and there are a few things, which looks inappropriate by now.

One thing has been issued in this Question:
[Why are more Pixel used in resulting PDF than in source html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476868/why-are-more-pixel-used-in-resulting-pdf-than-in-source-html)
So I use a modified Version of iText by now,
but these Problems are the same in iText 7.1.9

Here is a minimal Example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Worker4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String kongressURL = "http://www.little-football.de/megaMerge/target.html";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(kongressURL).get();
        System.out.println("-----Titel: " + doc.title());
        Element content = doc.child(0);
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        properties.setBaseUri(kongressURL);
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("content.pdf");
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(content.html(), new PdfDocument(writer), properties);
    }
}
```

So why the difference and how can I fix that?

PDF:
[image: PDF]

Chrome:
[image]

The essential part of the pom:

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.10</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/resources/itext7-layout-7.1.10-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/html2pdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

So maybe that are two Questions:

1. why is the blue bar broken?
2. why is the linklist positioned on the left side?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update: Question 1 seems related to the earlier Problem, which I mentioned. Both are too big background Images. Maybe the Solution wasn't the best because there is a common cause. I am searching for that. Or maybe I have to use the Method at an other PLace too.

Comment: I made up a far less complex html example:
http://www.little-football.de/megaMerge/test.html